# select value does not shows default value when using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why select tag with ng-options works correctly by showing the default selected value but same is not working if I use with ng-repeat.

here is the code,

```
  <!-- this works-->

<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectValue" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in availableOptions"> 
</select>

<!-- this also works-->

    <select ng-model="selectValue">
       <option ng-repeat="options in availableOptions" value="{{options.id}}" ng-selected="selectValue === options.id">{{options.name}}</option>
    </select> 

<!-- this doesnt works-->

<select ng-model="selectValue">
   <option ng-repeat="options in availableOptions" ng-value="options.id" ng-selected="selectValue === options.id">{{options.name}}</option>
</select>
```

in app.js,

```
$scope.selectValue="2";
    $scope.availableOptions = [
      {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
      {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
      {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
    ];
```

[image: Though the HTML shows the selected attribute, still its not rendered properly in the view]

Though the HTML shows the selected attribute, still its not rendered properly in the view

Here is the plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/VoGT8ViG77rnGQxtTtbM?p=preview) for the same

Comment: the first syntax is the preferred, recommended syntax; why are you trying to fix an issue with a non-preferred syntax?

Comment: Ya I know first method is preferred, but just to learn I tried the second method. Can you figure out why its not working??

Answer (score 0):

Though the correct way of having dropdown on a page should be using `ng-options` but the you could change your markup below to make it working with `ng-repeat` version.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="selectValue">
   <option ng-repeat="options in availableOptions" value="{{options.id}}">
     {{options.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/AtJH12dEI2mnYF5FayTF?p=preview)

Comment: but do you know why its not working if use with ngValue??

Comment: @MaheSirius its very wiered..the most worse part is it get worked when changed `option` tag to `<option ng-repeat="options in availableOptions" ng-value="options.id">{{options.id}}</option>`

Comment: ya its very weird . .Dont know how to figure it out.

Comment: @MaheSirius do you want anything else from me?